# How do I delete last entry of Firebase after several interval?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to delete new entries of Firebase after several intervals.

The required interval will be acquired from Spinner.
The data is fetched and displayed into recyclerView,
I want to delete it from recyclerView after time is selected from spinner but not the data before spinner is selected.

```
recyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {

        reference.orderByChild(userid).equalTo(userid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message will be deleted now ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                }
        );
    }
}, seconds);
```

The Whole node is being deleted,
I only want the last message to be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete only the last query result:

```
reference.orderByChild(userid).equalTo(userid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DataSnapshot lastSnapshot = null;
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {               
              lastSnapshot = childSnapshot;
            }
            if (lastSnapshot != null) {
                lastSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors   
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Is it clear how my answer differs from what you have? And why that should solve the problem? If not, spend time on figuring that out and asking questions about it, as without understanding this is just a code copying exercise. If it is clear how this is supposed to work: what happens if you set a breakpoint on the first line in `onDataChange` and step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: It Worked,Thanks for the solution and the Motivation :)

Answer (score 0):

after completing the interval ,  you have to find latest entry by :
orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addChildEventListener(...
{
delete node here by :
dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
}

Comment: Which Interval? Where do i write this code? @uzairIqbal